# Vue.js show hide multiple elements with data list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js, vue-component

I'm new in Vue.js, i'm using Vue+Webpack. I need that each link can show the data based on each id when they're clicked, and match with show attribute. I create it in `.vue` file.

```js
export default {
  el: 'skill',
  props: {
    skill: Object,
    selectedId: Number
  },
  computed: {
    show () {
      return this.skill.id === this.selectedId
    }
  },
  name: 'HomePage',
  data () {
    return {
      show_skill: 1,
      skills: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'css',
          items: '<li>CSS 3</li><li>Sass/Less</li><li>CSS Animations</li><li>CSS Frameworks : Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation, Bulma, Material Design</li>',
          show: true
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'js',
          items: '<li>Vanilla JS</li><li>jQuery</li><li>Angular JS</li><li>Vue JS</li><li>Ajax</li><li>JSON</li>',
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'html',
          items: '<li>HTML 5</li><li>SVG Animation</li><li>Canvas</li>',
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'general',
          items: '<li>Responsive Web Design</li><li>Adaptive Web Design</li><li>Hybrid Mobile App</li><li>Wordpress Template</li><li>Email Template</li>',
          show: false
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          title: 'tools',
          items: '<li>Git</li><li>Gulp/Grunt</li><li>Npm</li><li>Webpack</li><li>Bower</li><li>Sketch</li><li>Adobe XD</li><li>Adobe Illustrator</li><li>Adobe Photoshop</li><li>InVision</li><li>Marvel</li>',
          show: false
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>


<div class="c-skills">
  <a href="#" class="active" @click="skill.show">CSS</a>
  <a href="#">JS</a>
  <a href="#">HTML</a>
  <a href="#">Tools</a>
  <a href="#">General</a>
</div>         

<div class="c-desc" id="vn-skillset">
    <skill :selected-id="selectedId" :post="skill" @click="selectedId = skill.id">
      <h4 v-show="skill.show">{{ skill.title }}</h4>
      <ul v-show="skill.show">{{ skill.items }}</ul>
    </skill>
</div>
```

currently that code shows error : 
[image]

What is vue.esm? What is $mount? 
What the right things should I do to reach what i need? 
How to implement that?

Comment: can you make a codesandbox to mimic your issue? https://codesandbox.io/s/vue

Comment: like this @A.Lau?  https://codesandbox.io/s/k325km5lqr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you have to enclose all your HTML code into one `<div id="skill">` tag and set an id to that tag so you can target it in your Vue instance.

Moreover, since you're using the cdn version of Vue you must use `new Vue ({})` syntax to create your root Vue instance, once you already did you can use the `export default {}` object in your different components.

$mount is a built-in property and one of the life-cycle hooks of the Vue instance it's when your browser takes all your Vue code and try to mount it on top of the selected `<div>` tag in your HTML body, check this [Instance Lifecycle Hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html)

Here's an alternative version of your code :

```
<div id ="skill">

<div class="c-skills">
  <a href="#" @click="show(1)">CSS</a>
  <a href="#" @click="show(2)">JS</a>
  <a href="#" @click="show(3)">HTML</a>
  <a href="#" @click="show(4)">Tools</a>
  <a href="#" @click="show(5)">General</a>
</div>         

<div>
      <h4>{{ skill.title }}</h4>
      <ul v-html="skill.items"></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Vue Instance:

```
new Vue ({
  el: '#skill',
  data () {
    return {
    skill:{title:'',items:''},
      skills: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: 'css',
          items: '<li>CSS 3</li><li>Sass/Less</li><li>CSS Animations</li><li>CSS Frameworks : Bootstrap, Zurb Foundation, Bulma, Material Design</li>',
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: 'js',
          items: '<li>Vanilla JS</li><li>jQuery</li><li>Angular JS</li><li>Vue JS</li><li>Ajax</li><li>JSON</li>',
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: 'html',
          items: '<li>HTML 5</li><li>SVG Animation</li><li>Canvas</li>',
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          title: 'general',
          items: '<li>Responsive Web Design</li><li>Adaptive Web Design</li><li>Hybrid Mobile App</li><li>Wordpress Template</li><li>Email Template</li>',
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          title: 'tools',
          items: '<li>Git</li><li>Gulp/Grunt</li><li>Npm</li><li>Webpack</li><li>Bower</li><li>Sketch</li><li>Adobe XD</li><li>Adobe Illustrator</li><li>Adobe Photoshop</li><li>InVision</li><li>Marvel</li>',
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    show(x){

      for (var i =0; i<=this.skills.length; i++) {
  
        if (x == this.skills[i].id){
          this.skill.title = this.skills[i].title;
          this.skill.items = this.skills[i].items;
        }
      }       
   }      
  }
});
```

In your case, I highly recommend you to use vue-router property here is a useful tutorial for it :   [Vue Router documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/)

Comment: Your explanation is very helpful. Thanks! but i have another question from that 
" to create your root Vue instance, once you already did you can use the export default {} object in your different components."
in my local already did it, so i use export default {}, do you mean different components is another .vue file? or what?
because after implementing your alternative solution, there are 2 warnings : 
[Vue warn]: option "el" can only be used during instance creation with the `new` keyword.
[Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #skill .
what should i do @M.Abuaisha ?

Comment: i made codesandbox (thanks to @A.Lau) like in my local vue https://codesandbox.io/s/1wqkzon5j4 can you pls check it @M.Abuaisha ?

Comment: Ok since you already have your vue instance in the main.js file and you imported the App component there and you targeted the div with id ="app" in the index.html page it's all set, I have edited the code a bit and it's running well now

Comment: I tried to save my edits on top of your code but it didn't work so check this link https://codesandbox.io/s/l3nqn875p7

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is quite simple but you are misunderstanding some points so below is some points that you need to research more to implement what you need now

1. You are using `skill` as a component on the template but it's just a Object from props. So you need to learn how to create a component, declare and using it in another component.
2. Use `v-for` directive to generate a list of skills.
3. You need learn how to use `props` and `computed` properly.